# How do I switch from docker-compose to Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, bitnami

I'm trying to run Magento 2 locally, so I built built a Docker LAMP stack using docker compose. This is the `docker-compose.yml` portion related to the php container:

```
php:
    image: 'docker.io/bitnami/php-fpm:7.4-debian-10'
    ports:
      - 9001:9000
    volumes:
      - './docker/php/php.ini:/opt/bitnami/php/etc/conf.d/custom.ini'
    networks:
      - 'web'
```

and it works great. The point is that the bitnami image doesn't seem to have cron pre-installed, and for the sake of simplicity it's probably easier to have it directly in the php container (so I can reach it through the Magento cli functionalities, e.g. `bin/magento cron:install`)

So, I changed the php instruction into the docker-compose file from image to build, added a separated Dockerfile written like this:

```
FROM docker.io/bitnami/php-fpm:7.4-debian-10
```

I didn't even add the `RUN` instructions for adding packages. What I'm expecting at the moment is that by running  `docker-compose up -d --remove-orphan` the result is basically the same. But it's not, because refreshing the homepage now gives me a 503 error that doesn't seem to leave any trace into the log files, so I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: May you share the new docker-compose.yml you are using? Are you simply switching the "image" field by a "build" field properly pointing to the directory containing the new Dockerfile?

Comment: Correct. The rest of the docker-compose is basically all the other containers and volumes, but the problem is narrowable to this specific container. I was expecting the two solutions having the same effect (on which I could have started to build, adding the cron packages to the image), but they does not seem to.

Comment: TTBMK, indeed they should have the same effect. I suggest double-checking whether the `remove-orphan` is properly working with a simple `docker ps`, and posting the new `docker-compose.yml` for any bugs.